# Repairing Windows Bootloader

Tags: linux, windows, bootloader, gpt

I bought a new hard disk with 3 TiB of space where I wanted to install 3 different OSes. (1 Windows and 2 Linux) Since I had a 3 TiB hard disk, I needed to use GPT scheme which made it not possible for me to get Windows working.

Here is what I did trying to make it work:

At first, I installed Windows, which means that have the MS-DOS partition table which makes Windows bootable but doesn't allow the two other Linux OS to install. Since I don't have a UEFI mainboard, I can't install Windows with GPT directly.

So I changed the MS-DOS partition table to GPT with `gdisk` and the Linux Mint Live CD, which, of course, destroyed the Windows bootloader.

The error message I get when trying to load Windows tells me to fix Windows with the Recovery CD which is not possible because there I get the error message: not compatible version... because of the use of GPT, so I can't fix it with the CD.

But I can access my Window partition through my other Linux OS's, so maybe there is a possibility to install a new Bootloader via WINE or to repair the old one.

Question: How can I fix my bootloader problem without UEFI and without the Recovery CD or how can I install Windows with GPT without UEFI?

Comment: how is [tag:macos] relevant here?

Comment: Have you tried using Grub?

Comment: Yes i tried using grub but are there any console commands i could use to make it work?

Comment: you could try using Grub Customizer if you use Ubuntu to configure Grub and add Windows (not sure for UEFI though)

Comment: or see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Some facts:

Windows boot manager for BIOS booting is "bootmgr" - it can start Windows only from MBR style disk.

Windows boot manager for UEFI booting is "bootmgfw.efi" - it can start Windows only from GPT style disk.

'bootmgfw.efi' cannot be started directly by BIOS boot process.

**It is possible to install Windows to any partition using "dism.exe"**. Partition can be on a hard disk or on USB disk/flash drive in any style (MBR or GPT).

Boot manager can be seen as an independent part of OS.

**Now to question:**

How could we boot Windows (7/8/10 64-bit) installed on a partition on a hard disk which is in GPT style without having UEFI firmware?

**The answer:**

We need some knowledge about UEFI boot process for Windows OS - what is EFI System partition, what is inside "\EFI\boot" and inside "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot", what is Windows BCD.

We need some UEFI emulation software which could start Windows UEFI boot manager.

Emulation software for UEFI is for example **"DUET"** - Developer's UEFI Environment  - see [A BIOS to UEFI Transformation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/bios2uefi/) for further explanations.

DUET can be placed on hard disk or on USB flash drive and started from there by BIOS.

Hope this answers the question (without going into details).

Answer (score 0):

One way it to completely reinstall windows without using uefi (possibly everything)
This will require some install media

First you need to go into your bios/uefi settings and disable safeboot and then enable legacy boot, then reinstall making sure you boot from the legacy/bios mode for the install media, not uefi

Another way is to use the Windows Boot Manager using something like [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)

In the Windows install, install [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) or [Visual BCD Editor](https://www.boyans.net).
I cannot help you with VBCD as I have not used it.

With EasyBCD, if the installs weren't found, click <kbd>Add New Entry</kbd>, go through the process, If you still have grub installed, but not the main boot loader you can choose that, otherwise select the partition of a Linux install and finish the setup, dame with the other one

Comment: Thanks for the advice but i've already reinstalled windows without uefi which is then by default the msdos partition table which doesn't two others Linux aside when i change the partition table to gpt i have the indicated Problem. Isn't there a possibility to boot the OS on hdd from USB

Comment: @albert, i'm not meaning boot the os from the install medium or other usb, I'm meaning to configure either GRUB or Windows Boot Manager to be able to boot every thing, either by reinstalling everything, or attempting to do it with how you already have it

Comment: I think I got what you mean but aside from the BCDEdit tool i ve already tried those things and it doesn't work and unfortunately the BCDEdit is not free. But i heard there is a way to install a Bootloader on USB which makes starting windows on hdd possible

Comment: @albert, BCDEdit is a more advanced way of interacting with Windows Boot Manager than EasyBCD. I read the last sentence like `I don't wamt to boot the OS on HDD from USB` sorry for that, yes there are several boot tools. I've seen one in the install  medium creator: Unetbootin

Comment: Yeah but the question is how I can boot the OS from USB which is already on HDD  instead of reinstalling the whole OS. So I have to install a Windows Bootloader on USB with Unetbootin somehow

Comment: It won't be the Windows Boot Manager, It'll be more like a Grub Super Boot, or something else. to have it automatically boot that device you'll need to change your BIOS/UEFI settings, every one is different, so you're on your own there